Interpret AD "lastLogon" field
I have not been able to find a way to interpret the "lastLogon" field from a PowerShell cmdlet like;
[Get-ADComputer -Identity "ComputerName" -Properties *]
What I get is a string of numbers like example.Output from cmdlet This computer is offline[lost] so I don't believe I can use any of the win event commands.
Thank you, Kenny
tried Get-ADComputer -Identity "ComputerName" -Properties *

[DateTime]::FromFileTime('133541980705291112')

Welcome to SO.  Please do not post images of code or console output or error messages. Instead post the plain text and format it as code.  ... and please format your code properly using a [code block].
